# 'TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable' in Python while statement

Tags: python, pyautogui, rpa

I am a beginner developer just learning Python.

I'm using 'pyautogui' to create a bot that clicks a checkbox.

The code is running just the way I want it to.

But I don't know how to get out of the 'while' statement at the end.

When I click on all the checkboxes I get the following error:

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Below is the code I wrote.

```
import pyautogui
import PIL

pyautogui.sleep(2)

while True:
    x1=pyautogui.center(pyautogui.locateOnScreen("checkbox.png", region=(50, 50, 1000, 1000), confidence=0.9)) 
    pyautogui.moveTo(x1)
    pyautogui.click()
    sftp = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("sftp.png", region=(750, 450, 500, 500), confidence=0.7)
    pyautogui.sleep(0.5)
    print(x1)
    if x1 == None:
        break
        print("work is done")
```

Execute the above code and when it's done, the output will be something like this:

```
Point(x=212, y=859)
Point(x=212, y=877)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\project\a_\experi.py", line 7, in <module>
    x1=pyautogui.center(pyautogui.locateOnScreen("checkbox.png", region=(50, 50, 1000, 1000), confidence=0.9))
  File "c:\python39-32\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 581, in center
    return Point(coords[0] + int(coords[2] / 2), coords[1] + int(coords[3] / 2))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Looks like your `coords` is of type None

Comment: `center()` doesn't return anything, it simply centers screenshot location to a specific point.

Answer (score 0):

From the official [documentation of PyAutoGUI](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html#the-locate-functions), we can see that the locateOnScreen() function raises a *ImageNotFoundException* and returns *None* when it is unable to locate the image it is searching for. This error might occur due to the following reasons:

1. If there is an error in the image file name (has to be the same with the original image file name).
2. If there is an error in the extension of the image file (has to be the same with the original image extension).
3. If the pixels specified for the image are not matching. Generally, the pixels (region) should be a very close match to the actual image position. A less value for the confidence parameter can be tried to overlook negligible differences between the actual image position and the pixels specified.